# Is this the way to go for storing options from a dropdown with multiple selects?

Tags: mysql, forms

**Details**

I have a dropdown that allows multiple options to be selected. [image]

I want to easily and quickly search the database for these options.
To do so, I have opted to create a column in the DB for each option as set out below.

```
userid  | car |cdplayer|computer| 
*********************************
   785  |  1  |   0    |    1   |
```

Each of the columns uses TinyInt(1). If the option is selected I store the value 1, else I store 0. The problem I see with this method is that the table can get quite large if there are a lot of options. If I stored the options in a single column, I assume that it would be much harder to search the database for the columns, but then the database would be much smaller (maybe this doesn't matter at all though).

**Question**

Do you see any problems with the method I am currently employing? Is there a better way of achieving what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally considered poor database design. It makes it hard to add new options, since you have to update the database schema, and change all applications to know about this new column.

A better solution is an options table with columns `option_id` and `option_name`. Then you use a reference table `user_options` with columns `user_id` and `option_id` to link them.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling there was a better way, but I couldn't think of it on my own. I just wish I had asked this question earlier!

Answer (score 1):

A better structure might be to have a user table and an options table, and link those via an optionid.

```
userid | optionid |
*******************
  12   |    1     |
*******************
  12   |    3     |
*******************
  35   |    2     |
```

Options table:

```
optionid |       value        |
*******************************
   1     |        Car         |
*******************************
   2     |        CD          |
*******************************
   3     |        Computer    |
*******************************
```

Comment: The way you have displayed the tables makes it easier for me to understand. Thanks.